# set up amazon auto scaling command line tools windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i have downloaded the zip file of amazon auto scaling command line tools from this link:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2535

after having unziped it,and renamed it AWS (C:\AWS)

i have installed java and  created a bat file following the read me instructions below(README file):

## **Auto Scaling Command Line Tools

### Installation:

1. Ensure that JAVA version 1.5 or higher is installed on your system: (java -version)
2. Unzip the deployment zip file
3. Set the following environment variables:
   3.1 AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME - The directory where the deployment files were copied to
       check with:
          Unix: ls ${AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME}/bin should list as-create-auto-scaling-group ...)
          Windows: dir "%AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME%\bin" should list as-create-auto-scaling-group ...)
   3.2 JAVA_HOME - Java Installation home directory
4. Add ${AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME}/bin (in Windows: "%AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME%\bin") to your path

   ### Configuration:

Provide the command line tool with your AWS user credentials.  There
are two ways you can provide credentails: AWS keys, or using X.509
certificates.

### Using AWS Keys

1. Create a credential file: The deployment includes a template file ${AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME}/credential-file-path.template.
    Edit a copy of this file to add your information.
    On UNIX, limit permissions to the owner of the credential file: $ chmod 600 .
2. There are several ways to provide your credential information:
     a. Set the following environment variable: AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=
     b. Alternatively, provide the following option with every command --aws-credential-file 
     c. Explicitly specify credentials on the command line: --I ACCESS_KEY --S SECRET_KEY

### Using X.509 Certs

1. Save your cetificate and private keys to files: e.g. my-cert.pem
   and my-pk.pem.
2. There are two ways to provide the certificate information to the
   command line tool
   a.  Set the following environment variables:
       EC2_CERT=/path/to/cert/file
       EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/path/to/key/file
   b.  Specify the files directly on command-line for every command
        --ec2-cert-file-path=/path/to/cert/file --ec2-private-key-file-path=/path/to/key/file

   ### Running:
3. To check that your setup works properly, run the following command:
   $ as-cmd --help
     You should see the usage page for all Auto Scaling commands
   $ as-describe-auto-scaling-groups --headers
     You should see a header line. If you have auto scaling groups
     already configured, you will see a description line for each
     auto scaling group**

My  bat file looks like:

```
 REM Path should have bin\java.exe under it
 set AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME="C:\AWS"
 set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
 set PATH="%PATH%";"%AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME%\bin"
 REM Path to Primary Key and Certificate retrieved from AWS 
 set EC2_PRIVATE_KEY="C:\AWS\pv_pk.pem"
 set EC2_CERT="C:\AWS\cert-pk.pem"
 cls
 cmd
```

after executing my the bat file ,i try to execute the command ec2_describe_groups it's not recognized.What's wrong with my bat file.

Answer (score 0):

the command is "ec2-describe-group" not "ec2_describe_groups" please see the documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSecurityGroups.html